# Delete elements of an XML file using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, soap

I need to delete elements of an XML file using PHP.

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetVehiculesLocationResponse xmlns="http://google.fr/">
            <GetVehiculesLocationResult>
                <Location>
                    <idVH>001</idVH>
                    <date>2020-06-30T09:06:39</date>
                    <latitude>111111</latitude>
                    <longitude>11111</longitude>
                </Location>
                <Location>
                    <idVH>002</idVH>
                    <date>2020-04-02T13:45:51</date>
                    <latitude>1111111</latitude>
                    <longitude>111111</longitude>
                </Location>
                <Location>
                    <idVH>11111111</idVH>
                    <date>2020-03-24T21:49:46</date>
                    <latitude>1111111</latitude>
                    <longitude>11111111</longitude>
                </Location>
            </GetVehiculesLocationResult>
        </GetVehiculesLocationResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I want to delete elements (in this case `Location`) where `idVH` is a certain value (in this case 002)

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($result); 
$items = $xml1->xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/GetVehiculesLocationResponse/GetVehiculesLocationResult/Location[idVH = 002]");

foreach ($items as $i) unset($i[0]);
   echo $xml1->asXML();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the element `GetVehiculesLocationResponse` defines a new default namespace, so that and the child elements are all in that new namespace...

```
<GetVehiculesLocationResponse xmlns="http://google.fr/">
```

So first register the new namespace and then use it as a prefix in the lower level elements...

```
$xml1->registerXPathNamespace("d", "http://google.fr/");
$items = $xml1->xpath("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/d:GetVehiculesLocationResponse/d:GetVehiculesLocationResult/d:Location[d:idVH = '002']");
```

Comment: You can alter the XPath to add extra values, something like `d:idVH = '002' or d:idVH = '001'`

Comment: how to delete two two element with idVH equal 002 and 001

Answer (score 0):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (sibling to XPath), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files and especially best suited for processing many elements. In fact, you can even pass parameters like `001` from PHP to XSLT. PHP can run XSLT 1.0 scripts with its [xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class using `DOMDocument` library.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:googl="http://google.fr/">  
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <!-- DEFINE PARAM WITH DEFAULT -->
   <xsl:param name="id_param">001</xsl:param>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- KEEP NODES BY PARAM VALUE -->
    <xsl:template match="googl:GetVehiculesLocationResult">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="googl:Location[googl:idVH != $id_param]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP** *(pass parameters to XSLT in loop)*

```
// LOAD XML
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$xml->load($data->xmlFile);

// LOAD XSLT 
$xsl = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');   
$xsl->load('XSLT_Script.xsl');

// INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

foreach($param as array('001', '002')) { 
    // SET PARAMETER VALUE
    $proc->setParameter('', 'id_param', $param);

    // TRANSFORM SOURCE
    $xml = $proc->transformToDoc($xml);
}

// ECHO TO SCREEN
echo $xml->saveXML();

// SAVE TO FILE
file_put_contents($data->xmlFile, $xml);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetVehiculesLocationResponse xmlns="http://google.fr/">
         <GetVehiculesLocationResult>
            <Location>
               <idVH>11111111</idVH>
               <date>2020-03-24T21:49:46</date>
               <latitude>1111111</latitude>
               <longitude>11111111</longitude>
            </Location>
         </GetVehiculesLocationResult>
      </GetVehiculesLocationResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/EUKSF29849)